# User defined variable in PHPMyAdmin's console not recognized

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, user-defined-variables

I'm testing user defined variable directly in PHPMyAdmin's console.

I've observed that if I create:

```
SET @myVariable = 14;
```

I execute it, and then try to use it in another query during the same session:

```
SELECT * FROM tblstaff WHERE staffid = @myVariable;
```

I execute it too but then I receive an empty table.

Now if I execute the exact same queries but in one go, the table returned contains the right info I need.

This does not look like a normal behavior to me. I'm still in the same session so the user defined variable should be recognized.

Can someone tell me if this behavior is normal in PHPMyAdmin? When I look at Youtube videos in other environments than PHPMyAdmin it seems like people don't have problems executing queries one after another.

Thank you :)

Comment: For each interaction with Database server a new connection will be established, so the content of previously defined session variables will be NULL. You can check this with `SELECT connection_id()`

Comment: Indeed, I just tested it. That explains the behavior observed. Thanks.